# musicbrainzngs: grab ID from artist search

Tags: python, dictionary, musicbrainz

Currently learning python to forgive me but I am using this musicbrainzngs API to grab the ID of an artist's name from user input. It should then take the ID and list 5 random songs from the artist in question. Right now I am trying to figure out to get the ID from the relevant artist so it can be then used in a separate search to return 5 songs from that artist.

documentation API: https://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/usage/

Code as shown:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import musicbrainzngs
import sys
musicbrainzngs.set_useragent("LyricsWordCount", "1.0", "azizn03",)
#musicbrainzngs.set_hostname("musicbrainz.org", use_https=False)

artist = input("Enter Artist Name ")

result = musicbrainzngs.search_artists(artist="" + artist, type="group",
                                   country="GB")
for artist in result['artist-list']:
    print("{name}: {id}".format(name=artist["name"], id=artist['id']))
```

results:

```
Enter Artist Name coldplay
Coldplay: cc197bad-dc9c-440d-a5b5-d52ba2e14234
Viva La Coldplay: 62c54a75-265f-4e13-ad0a-0fb001559a2e
The Beatles: b10bbbfc-cf9e-42e0-be17-e2c3e1d2600d
The Rolling Stones: b071f9fa-14b0-4217-8e97-eb41da73f598
Pink Floyd: 83d91898-7763-47d7-b03b-b92132375c47
George Frideric Handel: 27870d47-bb98-42d1-bf2b-c7e972e6befc
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: What's not working with your code?

Comment: The question is I want to grab the ID i.e. the string after the first coldplay result from the first result and store that in a varible.@myke @DYZ

Comment: @myke This was the output from that https://pastebin.com/DkvCV7Qd

Comment: What is that the output of?

Comment: From what you gave me but the comment seems to be gone now
result['artist-list'][0]['id']
print(result) 
@myke

Comment: Not ```print(result)```; try ```print(result['artist-list'][0]['id'])```.

Comment: @myke If you wanna add your answer on ill marked it as solved.

Comment: Done. You should add some more specifics to your question. E.g. this: "I am just trying to understand how to grab the ID of the first result so I can then use that ID for another search to output the songs of that artist. The libary uses the ID rather than the artist name."

Comment: @myke Okay, I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`id_of_first_artist = result['artist-list'][0]['id']`